# How to focus Textbox with Alt + letter

Tags: .net, winforms, user-interface, setfocus

I need to quick focus the text box using **Alt+Letter** combination. In my form for each textbox is a label. For this label I can specify name as **'&My Label'** and **M** letter will be underlined when I press the Alt button. But how I can focus the textbox (in winforms)?

P.S. As I remember WPF has possibility to bind label with textbox. And if label get focus textbox will get focus automatically.

Comment: Winforms? WPF? WebForms? MVC?

Comment: I need to do this in Winforms

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works automatically. Just make sure the `TextBox` you want to focus is the next one in the tab order, i.e. if the `Label` has `TabIndex` = 0, the `TextBox` needs `TabIndex` = 1.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Tab Index. It will automatically handled. You can view/set the Tab index by

> View > Tab Order menu